# JavaScript: Difference between Reflect.get() and obj['foo']

Tags: javascript, reflection

Can't understand why I should use `Reflect.get(obj, 'foo')` instead of `obj['foo']`, or why the first one is useful as we can do the same thing using the good and old object bracket notation. Can someone please elaborate?

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};
obj['foo'];
Reflect.get(obj, 'foo');
```

Comment: *"The `Reflect.get` method allows you to get a property on an object. It is like the property accessor syntax as a function."* – That's pretty much it. It's the same thing, but as a function. Can come in handy in functional programming.

Comment: @deceze but you can already create a closure anywhere you might need such a function...

Comment: @Jon Sure, but this one's built-in!  … Yeah, that's all I got for that as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, a *pedantic* answer to your question would be that they are entirely different: a property accessor returns a *reference* to a property, while `Reflect.get` returns its *value*.

From the practical standpoint that doesn't make any difference since property references are always dereferenced on the right side.

One practical usage of `Reflect.get` would be with its third argument, which, when combined with a `Proxy`, can be used to create different "views" of the same data.

```js
let numbersView = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
        return receiver(target[key])
    }
});

let decimal = x => String(x);

let english = x => {
    if (x === 1) return 'one';
    if (x === 2) return 'two';

};

let v = numbersView({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
});

console.log(Reflect.get(v, 'a', decimal))
console.log(Reflect.get(v, 'a', english))
```

This example is a bit made-up, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 21):

## `return Reflect.get(...arguments);`

`Reflect.get` refers to the getter if any. The `foo` getter is given the proxied object, `receiver` (`receiver === case1`), for its `this`. Meaning, the `get` trap for the `bar` is called as well.

```js
const case1 = new Proxy({
    get foo() {
        console.log("The foo getter", this);
        return this.bar;
    },
    bar: 3
}, {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("The Proxy get trap", ...arguments);
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
});
console.log(case1.foo);
```

```
> case1.foo
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The foo getter ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶bar ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶3
```

---

## `return target[property];`

Using the unproxied object, `target`. This also triggers the `foo` getter, but notice: `this` for the `foo` getter is the unproxied object, `target`. The `get` trap for the `bar` is not called.

```js
const case2 = new Proxy({
    get foo() {
        console.log("The foo getter", this);
        return this.bar;
    },
    bar: 3
}, {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("The Proxy get trap", ...arguments);
        return target[property];
    }
});
console.log(case2.foo);
```

```
> case2.foo
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The foo getter ▶{bar: 3}
▶3
```

---

## `return receiver[property];`

Using the proxied object, `receiver` (`receiver === case3`). `receiver[property]` refers to the `get` trap, not the getter, causing an infinity loop.

```js
const case3 = new Proxy({
    get foo() {
        console.log("The foo getter", this);
        return this.bar;
    },
    bar: 3
}, {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("The Proxy get trap", ...arguments);
        return receiver[property];
    }
});
console.log(case3.foo);
```

```
> case3.foo
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
▶The Proxy get trap ▶{bar: 3} ▶foo ▶Proxy {bar: 3}
……
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Now you get it.

---

## Which to use

> Can't understand why I should use `Reflect.get(obj, 'foo')` instead of `obj['foo']`

While using the `Reflect` verbs is idiomatic for `Proxy` trap implementation, there's actually no *should*. It depends on your use case. If your `target` ("unproxied") object does not have getters or you're not insterested in what properties its getters are accessing ("secondary property accesses"), you might not need the fancy-looking `Reflect`. On the other hand, if you'd like to trigger the trap for all kinds of property accesses, primary or secondary, you would need `Reflect`.

For me, I always stick to `return Reflect.get(...arguments);`.