# Proxy returning different value from expected

Tags: javascript, difference

Just like the title says, i'm using an proxy to modify WebSocket but, for some reason the toString function(of the WebSocket proxy) is returning different values even though the proxy's get handler is returning target[p]..
here's the code i'm using.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         proxy test
// @namespace    idk
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing proxy.
// @author       miniscripter
// @match        https://www.google.com
// @grant        unsafeWindow
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==
console.clear();
console.log(WebSocket.toString());
unsafeWindow.WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
    get(target, p, receiver) {
        console.log(target);
        return target[p]; //should return the target's property...
    }
});
console.log(unsafeWindow.WebSocket.toString());
```

[image]

As you can see, instead of returning the same toString value, it is returning an different value which seems to be the toString value of the proxy, why is this happening?

The new toString should return the same value as the original seeing that the Proxy retuns the original one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the `toString` by itself, so when you call that, the `this` is all "messed up" (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used) for a complete overview of how `this` works). You need to bind it back to `target` so that the `this` inside still points to `WebSocket`:

```js
console.log(WebSocket.toString());

WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
    get(target, p, receiver) {
        return target[p].bind(target);
    }
});

console.log(WebSocket.toString());
```

Also, consider using `Reflect.get(target, p, receiver)` instead of `target[p]`, depending on what you want to do (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639309/javascript-difference-between-reflect-get-and-objfoo) for details).